# Load URL without a webpage using php for iOS app

Tags: javascript, php, ios, swift

Without making it too complicated

I have an iOS app that loads a URL via an NSURLSession. That URL is some php which echoes back a response from a database. That response is a URL.

At this time the iOS App receive the URL as NSData and converts it into a URL and start a new NSURLSession with that URL.

What I want is to call /load /execute that URL without echoing it back to the iOS app first.

I tried javascript but that requires a browser window to be loaded but the NSURLSession does not load a browser.

Is what Im trying to do possible?

Thanks

Comment: You're just trying to basically fire/request a URL without opening it in the webpage? 

If so you can make an HTMLImageElement request and it will fire that URL for you, i.e. 



`var x = new Image;
x.src = 'http://the.url.com/p?url=12318384';`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, and I'm not an iOS developer, but maybe `header("location: $url")` in your php script, where `$url` is the url you want?

Comment: Couldn't get the first response to work. That does not mean it doesn't just in my case it didn't.

Comment: header("location:$url"); worked after I put ob_start(); at the start of the $url page. Will accept as answer if presented as @mattslone thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `header("location: $url")` in your php script instead of echoing, where `$url` is the url you want.